# Error of CSRF verification failed. Request aborted

Tags: python, django

I have a code,there is an error of CSRF verfication failed, Request aborted.
In form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/jobb/" class="form-horizontal" id="jobform" name="jform" enctype="multipart/form-data" >{% csrf_token %}
```

In views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def jobform(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        getintable = job(app_id = request.POST['jobid'],start_on = request.POST['starton'], end_on = request.POST['endon'],timeframe = request.POST['timeframe'],odeskid = request.POST['odeskid'],hourlyrate = request.POST['hourlyrate'],assigne = request.POST['assigne'],clientid = request.POST['clientid'])
        getintable.save()
        return render_to_response('jobsform.html')
    else:
        return render_to_response('interviewform.html')
```

Comment: did you add `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` in the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` of your `settings.py` too ?

Comment: Yes I add  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', in settings.py

Comment: Have you set to `true` `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE` or `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE` in settings.py and you are working without `https`?

Comment: as you use csrf_excempt in the view, try to drop the csrf_token from your template if it's really what you need otherwise put csrf_protect decorator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because you are not returning a `RequestContext` instance.  To fix this you can use the [`render` shortcut](http://django.me/render) as Suhail suggested; or you can pass in request context as a third argument to `render_to_response`.

In addition, you really should be using [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/), which automate a lot of the boilerplate code one would write.

Here is how your code would look like:

You would put this code in a file called `forms.py`, which is in the same directory as `views.py`:

```
from myapp.models import Job

class JobForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
```

In your `views.py`, you can do the following:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from myapp.forms import JobForm

def jobform(request):
    ctx = {'form': JobForm(request.POST or {})}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return redirect('/some/url')
        else:
           return render(request, 'interviewform.html', ctx)
    else:
        return render(request, 'interviewform.html', ctx)
```

In `interviewform.html`:

```
<form method="POST"
      class="form-horizontal"
      id="jobform" name="jform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form }}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using render, you don't even need csrf_exempt decorator. sinc you added csrf token in template(`{% csrf_token %}`):

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def jobform(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        getintable = job(app_id = request.POST['jobid'],start_on = request.POST['starton'], end_on = request.POST['endon'],timeframe = request.POST['timeframe'],odeskid = request.POST['odeskid'],hourlyrate = request.POST['hourlyrate'],assigne = request.POST['assigne'],clientid = request.POST['clientid'])
        getintable.save()
        return render(request,'jobsform.html')        
    return render(request,'interviewform.html')
```

Comment: may be the OP really needs the `@csrf_exempt` for that function. I was surprised too and was going to suggest `@csrf_protect` ;) So may be the token csrf_token in the form is not required too

Comment: @FoxMaSk if he is adding `@csrf_exempt` then he did not need to pass `{% csrf_token %}` in templates. more over render_to_response is an old version which requires context `context_instance=RequestContext(request))`.